# css for displaying div tag over a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display the calendar while clicking anchor tag and vice versa.I write the calendar code in div. Now I want to display the calendar over the page without sliding the this div.
Now it is display as

[image]

But I want to display as next image

[image]

```html
<a class="aastext">Payroll Calender</a> 
<div id='cal' class='cal'></div> 
<table>
    <!-- table code -->
</table>
```

```css
.cal, .pass1{
    display: none;
    width : 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aastext").click(function(){
        $(".cal").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: can u provide an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take your calendar out of document flow by giving it `position: absolute`. This way it won't affect the position of other sibling elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".aastext").click(function()
    {
        $(".cal").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.cal
{
    font-size: 10px;
    display:none;
    width :50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="aastext">Payroll Calender</a> 
<div id='cal' class='cal'>calendar</div> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `position: absolute` to your `.cal`

Answer (score 1):

```
First make your calendar position absolute:

.cal, .pass1{
    display: none;
    width : 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position : absolute;
    z-index:999
}
```

Now get the position of the anchor and accordingly set the position of calendar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aastext").click(function(){
        var anchorOffset=$(this).offset();
        var anchorHt=$(this).height();
        $(".cal").css("top",(anchorOffset.top+anchorHt)+"px");
        $(".cal").css("left",anchorOffset.left+"px");
        $(".cal").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```